# Questions about L4D2 game variable modifications

Tags: discussion, questions

I'd like to play with some game variables of L4D2's weapons, items and others, but I don't know which vars do what, how to properly extract the official var files from game libs, create a steam workshop submission and make it work on someone else's computer other than mine properly.

Example questions:

- How do I change weapon clip capacity in L4D2?
- How do I change the number of pellets fired from a shotgun in L4D2?
- How to make grenade launcher projectile sticky and timed in L4D2?
- What behavior parameters do zombies have in L4D2?
- Is there a way to change boomer bile effect duration in L4D2?
- I made a new weapon script, how do I add it to L4D2?

Are these kinds of questions acceptable here?

Comment: This site is for asking questions about the gamedev SE site itself. Beyond that your question here likely wouldn't be a fit for the main site since it's very broad and essentially asking for someone to write a tutorial for you. I suggest you check out some modding guides for L4D2.

Comment: @Byte56 I was meaning to ask if these types of questions are ok on gamedev, but didn't find an "allowed-questions" tag on this meta, so it may have looked like I was actually asking all that here.

Comment: Mod questions are allowed, but as I said, your questions is very broad and not a good fit. If you can be more specific about your question that would be great. Just because the topic is allowed doesn't mean any questions in that topic are allowed. They still need to be reasonably scoped.

Comment: I just added some example question titles which should be narrow enough on their own. What do you think, could someone answer them here?

Comment: I'm the wrong person to ask. Personally, I think that only very rarely does a modding question fit here. I think they're better suited for a forum about modding that game. I think all the question titles you've added look too broad. The best way to find out if a question is a fit is to ask the question on the main site.